# R: extract vector name from value in dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to create vectors from dataframe rows and use one of the cell values as the vector name. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("michel","nadia","carole"),
                 cities=c("Paris,Montreal","Chicago,Denver","Beijing,Bankok"))
```

...and I would like to get a vector (for example from the first row), like this:

```
michel <- c("Paris","Montreal")
```

How can we do this in R?

Thanks!

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we split the city names into vectors:

```
cities <- strsplit(as.character(df$cities), ",")
```

And we give the list entries the names and use `list2env()` to copy each entry to the global environment:

```
names(cities) <- df$name
list2env(cities, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The result are vectors containing the city names in separated entries, for each name:

```
> michel
[1] "Paris"    "Montreal"
> nadia
[1] "Chicago" "Denver" 
> carole
[1] "Beijing" "Bankok"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` into a `list` of named vectors and use `list2env` for creating multiple objects in the global env (not recommended)

```
list2env(split(as.character(df$cities), df$name), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

If we need to separate the 'cities'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate_rows(cities) %>% 
    {split(as.character(.$cities), .$name)} %>%
     list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

and now check the `ls()` for the 'name' objects created in the global env

---

Or another option is to extract the elements into a `list`, then convert it to a named list with `deframe` and use `list2env`

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(cities = str_extract_all(cities, "\\w+")) %>% 
     deframe %>%
     list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or for a single row

```
assign(as.character(df$name)[1], 
      scan(text = as.character(df$cities)[1], what = "", sep=","))
```

Now, check the `ls()` and the 'michel' object would be found

```
michel
#[1] "Paris"    "Montreal"
```

Comment: Wow, `enframe()` and `deframe()` seem super useful! I also didn't know about `separate_rows()`. You seem to know all the little helpful functions out there! Learning a lot from your answers - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that data frames in R can have list columns, so you could just convert the `cities` column to a list of vectors. That way everything is still organized neatly in a data.frame and you can access vectors for specific names by subsetting the data frame

```
df$cities <- strsplit(as.character(df$cities), ',')

df
#     name          cities
# 1 michel Paris, Montreal
# 2  nadia Chicago, Denver
# 3 carole Beijing, Bankok

df$cities[[which(df$name == 'michel')]]
# [1] "Paris"    "Montreal"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. A little sub-question: once we have a dataframe with a list column, how can we transpose the dataframe so that the list elements are shown in separate rows, and the name colum is used as the column headers?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the operation you describe is called "unnest"ing data in dplyr terms. If you load dplyr with `library(dplyr)`, you can then use the `unnest_longer` function to separate elements of the list column into rows. Here the code would be `df %>% unnest_longer(cities)` (run after the strsplit code above). There is also another function, `unnest_wider`, for splitting the elements into separate columns rather than rows.